# Create array of shortcode enclosures with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

The function of the codes I have is to detect any entries with square bracket enclosures. It will then display in html using jquery. I am trying to create a shortcode for my blogger site to display images, videos, etc..., though I am not sure if this is the right way. The codes are perfectly working according to my needs but each time I want to create another enclosure and "return", I have to do it separately.
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jrog53mt/1/)

```
  [[Link1]] [[Link2]]
  [img]http://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg[/img]

$(".test").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g, "<a href='#$1'>$1</a>");
});
$(".test").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\[img](.+?)\[\/img\]/g, "<img src='$1'>");
});
```

Is it possible to combine the codes and create arrays of unique shortcode enclosures then have its corresponding "return" as well? I want to add enclosures such as [aa][/aa],[bb][/bb],etc...
Thanks and sorry about my english :)

Comment: Please don't bypass the requirement of including code by including a dummy code block.  If the message says you need to include code then you should include relevant code.

Comment: any explanation why you down voted it? If you have a proper suggestion, maybe you can edit it instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `.replace()`'s

```
[[Link1]] [[Link2]]
[img]http://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg[/img]

$(".test").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g, "<a href='#$1'>$1</a>").replace(/\[img](.+?)\[\/img\]/g, "<img src='$1'>");
});
```

or

```
$(".test").html(function(i, html) {
  return html
      .replace(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g, "<a href='#$1'>$1</a>")
      .replace(/\[img](.+?)\[\/img\]/g, "<img src='$1'>")
});
```

for very clear readability.

You can also build local variable, like this

```
$(".test").html(function(i, html) {
  var buildhtml = html
      .replace(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g, "<a href='#$1'>$1</a>")
      .replace(/\[img](.+?)\[\/img\]/ig, "<img src='$1'>");

  while (buildhtml.match(/\[(b|i|u|strong|em)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/i)) {
      buildhtml = buildhtml.replace(/\[(b|i|u|strong|em)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/ig,"<$1>$2<\/$1>");
  }
  return buildhtml;
});
```

Because some elements need to be recursed over til they don't exist in bbml form anymore, and in this example, we can get nested b/i/u/em/strong, but we have to loop over it in case one is nested within another.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for your time. I will play with the codes and hope u'r always there if I have more queries :)

Comment: By the way, I really don't know about jquery, I only knew css. After research, I am just doing some trial and errors :)

Comment: Hi sir, I updated the fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/czxfe36v/1/ ), just some questions... 1. line #2 is removed but still working, is it necessary to be there?
2. line #8, if I remove b|i|u|strong|em inside .match, it is working still, is it necessary to be there?

Comment: Line 1 doesn't have to be there, that's correct. The while loop does need to be there, check out http://jsfiddle.net/czxfe36v/2/ and notice how the `[i]` tag isn't replaced? This is the way that regex works, the string is not re-checked after the match for within text that has already been processed. So, we use a while loop that cycles until there's no longer a match.

Comment: thanks for your reply :) I can actually use this for adding videos on my posts and even to the comment sections, the question is, if this is efficient enough or there will be no problems on the future? Please enlighten me :)

Comment: It is efficient enough, for sure. As it is *client-side*, there are no concerns with tons of requests at the same time. A smartphone has enough processing power to handle simple regex like this before the user even sees the content it is applying to.

Comment: That's a relief! Last question Sir, if I want to apply the image part in another div (e.g..test2), should I just create another set or there's a better way to do this? http://jsfiddle.net/czxfe36v/3/